# GAP — compute kernel of a matrix with coefficients in a finite ring

Tags: ring-theory, homology-cohomology, gap, free-modules

I need to compute first cohomology group with coefficients in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^m$ of specific finite groups. I reduced the computation of cocycles to the following problem: **compute the kernel of a matrix $A$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$**.

1. How do I compute it in general? Is there some good algorithm?
2. Is there a GAP function / package for that?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: GAP seems to have a way to do this when $n$ is a prime power: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap24.html#X8593A5337D3B2C70. I'm not a GAP expert, but when I tried computing the null space of a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, I got an error, so it may not be implemented for general $n$.

Comment: Thanks @JohnPalmieri, yeah, I need to do it for all sorts of numbers, not just prime powers, but maybe I could compute it for all maximal prime powers dividing $n$ and then piece it together with Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Indeed there isn't anything pre-cooked if $n$ is not a prime power, probably because the structure is a bit messy. I think one could construct it using the Hermite normal form (I.e. $\Z$-kernel) , but it requires more than just to reduce the $\Z$ kernel and I have not thought it through what the structure of the kernel as a set actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `BasisNullspaceModN` for that (it is undocumented, unfortunately, though we could change that in the next version of GAP). See also [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3329997/12415), which also describes a function `NullspaceModN` implemented using `BasisNullspaceModN`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Max. Does the fact that the function is undocumented mean that I need to read it every time I start GAP? Atm my GAP (4.9.2) doesn't recognise it as a function.

Comment: I was unclear: `NullspaceModN` is only defined in my other linked answer. I clarified my answer here now.