# GAP — NullspaceModQ not working

Tags: gap

I am using the [GAP (Groups, Algorithms and Programming)](https://www.gap-system.org) system. For some reason the function [NullspaceModQ](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap24.html#X86AE919983B242E2) (which is supposed to give a left kernel of matrix modulo a prime power $Q$) works incorrectly. While

```
NullspaceModQ([[4]],8)
```

correctly gives

```
[[0],[2],[4],[6]]
```

as an aswer, when I try

```
NullspaceModQ([[2]],8)
```

I get

```
[[0]]
```

Does anyone have any idea about what is wrong?

Comment: A very interesting one is `NullspaceModQ([[9]],81)`, which gives `[[0],[9],[18]]` as an answer.

Comment: I think you want https://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Leo no, this is a question about [GAP](https://gap-system.org) and the right tag is used - but for such kind of questions GAP Forum or GAP Support may be better. If you think that you have discovered a bug in the GAP system, the  recommended way to report it is to use the [GAP issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/issues).

Comment: So, it happened to be a bug! Thank you for reporting it @PawełPiwek!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a long-standing bug in GAP (I just verified that it already occurs in GAP 4.4). I logged it in our issue tracker (see [here](https://github.com/gap-system/gap/issues/3614)), and hopefully this will be fixed in a future GAP version.

In the meantime, you can `BasisNullspaceModN` instead, which is undocumented, but is still perfectly safe to use; it is also likely to be more efficient if there are many solutions, as it only returns a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the null space, not all its elements. And from the basis, it's a an easy exercise to get all solutions. As a bonus, it supports arbitrary moduli, not just prime powers.

Indeed, here is a function which does the same as `NullspaceModQ` but for all moduli (it could be optimized, but for huge problems you are better of working with the basis instead anyway).

```
NullspaceModN := function(M, n)
  local B, coeffs;
  B := BasisNullspaceModN(M, n);
  coeffs := Cartesian(ListWithIdenticalEntries(Length(B), [0..n-1]));
  return Set(coeffs, c -> c * B mod n);
end;
```